# Some websites displaying extremely scaled down pages on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome displays some websites at a very small scale relative to the screen resolution, as you can see in this pic:

[image]
(Alternatively: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1cii.png))

The same thing happens for pictures loaded in the browser, but the effect is even bigger (the pics show a minuscule preview in the browser page.

I'm using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Other browsers don't have this issue. If I zoom in 500% the page text is more legible, but the page content is displayed in a small, fixed area in the tab (~15% page width). I had the same issues with Chromium builds, so I installed Chrome to get rid of that, which worked only for a while. I'm not aware if this has been going since I installed Chrome, because it only seems to happen on some sites.

Comment: Did you try disabling extensions? Because it is only happening on some pages, it may be a result of an ad blocker removing components from the page.

Comment: Yes, I tested again, after I disabled all the extensions and it shows the same issue. It doesn't seem to be caused by extensions or any particular Chrome flags. I also reset the flags to their defaults. I can post another pic with all extensions disabled showing the same issue, if necessary.

Comment: I figured you would've already tried that. Just making sure. Windows 8 does some weird stuff with high dpi displays and multi monitors. Do you think that is a factor here? Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: It only happens in Chrome. Firefox and IE display all websites right. I don't have multiple monitors, just a 1920/1080 monitor. So the issue seems to be on the Chrome side only. I also checked each website which had this issue with the developer console to make sure there are no experimental CSS rules used on the page, but didn't find anything that would turn off this weird page scaling.

Comment: OK, so I had this issue before, now it's back. the jQuery site has the same issue displaying on a very small scale. It didnt use to be like that when I installed Chrome first. So I suppose this must be caused by some later update or installation.

Comment: Re-installing Chrome fixed the issue. It might be caused by Google detecting if you use an ad blocker and messing up with how some sites display. I had no other extension installed but an ad blocker and the issue was still there even with this extension disabled. I see no other explanation, but Google probably starting a war against ad blockers (see the recent case with Ublock origin).

Answer (score 2):

I navigated to `chrome://flags` and clicked the button in the upper right hand corner labeled `Reset All To Default`. That did the trick for me.